# Parameterize Managed Private Endpoint in Blob Linked Service ADF

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I need to use multiple Blob Storage Accounts in ADF. I am trying to create a single linked service for all storages with parameters. I unable to parameterized managed private endpoint. When I hardcode storage name then managed private endpoint (which has been created in ADF) gets selected automatically. Is there a way to parameterize it through Advance->JSON OR by any other way? ][image: Blob Linked Service]

Unable to parameterize managed private endpoint. Did not find any Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Azure data factory and storage account in azure portal. I setup the Integration Runtime as mention below

[image]

I created managed private endpoint in Azure Data factory.
Manage->Security->managed private endpoint
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

After creation of managed private endpoint we need to approve in storage account settings. for that I click on
Manage approval in azure portal which mentioned above. It takes me to below page

[image]

select private end point and click on approve which mentioned below.
It approves the private endpoint.

Image for reference:

[image]

Managed private endpoint is created and approved successfully.

we can achieve Parameterize Managed Private Endpoint in Blob Linked Service ADF using below Json script

```
{
    "name": "DataLakeBlob",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "StorageAccountEndpoint": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "https://<storage AccountName>.blob.core.windows.net"
            }
        },
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sasUri": "@{linkedService().StorageAccountEndpoint}"
        },
        "description": "Test Description"
    }
}
```

Mark the Specify dynamic contents in JSON format when test connection it connected successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

This works from my end please check from your end.